# Writing equality tests in an if statement

Tags: if-statement

I wanted to see if someone could shed some light on this for me.  When I was using the Checkstyle plugin for Eclipse, I got a warning message on the following statement (not exactly this, but this form):

```
if (x != y)
{
   do();
}
```

Why is this a problem?

**Edit**: I apologize, I should have been more clear with my question.  Thanks very much for your answers; they actually helped me with a completely different problem.

The warning that I got recommended that I not use a test of the form "x != y", but instead use a test of the form "x = y".  I'm wondering why one would be better than the other.

Comment: We need to see the actual code, and the actual warning message to be of any help.

Comment: +1 for Bill's comment. When you've got a warning or error and you're asking for help, *always* give the text of the warning/error - and preferably code which definitely produces that warning/error. Code which is "not exactly this" often omits or shifts the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

The default setting for the [LeftCurly](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#LeftCurly) checker is "eol". This means that you are enforcing the rule that if statements (and similar blocks) should look like this:

```
if (x != y) {
    do();
}
```

If you prefer the style you showed in the question, use the "nl" setting, described in the [lcurly policy](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/property_types.html#lcurly) section of the Checkstyle manual.

You can modify the setting in Eclipse like this:

1. From Window, choose Preferences.
2. If needed, create a new check configuration (usually by copying one of the unmodifiable originals) and make it the default.
3. Double-click the new configuration, click Blocks, then double-click Left Curly Brace Placement. Modify and save.

Answer (score 0):

See the Checkstyle's check description + rationale:  [Standard Checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html)

Answer (score -1):

Is there a "else"?

I think that if you wrote something like that

```
if (x != y)
{
   do();
}
else 
{
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

I'd recomend too

```
if (x == y)
{
   doSomethingElse();
}
else 
{
   do();
}
```

Comment: If you vote down, please at least tell, what your problem with that answer was. Downvotes can be helpful, but only if one can learn from it.

Comment: This recommendation has to do with how you write if conditions, not brace style.